# run npm ci hangs on docker build ubuntu

Tags: docker, ionic-framework, npm, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to build a docker file for an ionic project, on ubuntu virtualbox. Here's the dockerfile:

```
# Build
FROM beevelop/ionic AS ionic
# Create the application directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install the application dependencies
# We can use wildcard to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are considered
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm --verbose ci
# Bundle app source
COPY . .
RUN ionic build

## Run 
FROM nginx:alpine
#COPY www /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=ionic /usr/src/app/www /usr/share/nginx/html
```

My problem is that the build gets stuck on step 4 (`RUN npm --verbose ci`) It starts downloading some packages, but then it hangs at some point.
I tried different solution:

```
npm clean cache
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

removing `package-lock.json`

But nothing works, any help will be greatly apprecited. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To whoever experienced this problem, it was to due to internet connection. Keep trying until it downloads all the packages.

Comment: Yes, we have a lot of issues of `npm ci` hanging in our CI/CD pipeline and it started when we experienced internet connectivity issues. It seems that even a short outage puts this command in a stuck state and even when the connection comes back it stays stuck.

Answer (score 0):

For me restarting the docker daemon fixed this issue.